# How to delete the cookie while customer logged out in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3.3, cookie, logout

I wish to delete cookies while the customer clicked the log out button?

Can you please suggest us the best way to do it in magento 2

Answer (score 2):

You can use ***customer_logout*** event and clear cookies using Observer.

Create files in your modules as follows:

1. **Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/events.xml** :

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
       <event name="customer_logout">
          <observer instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\Frontend\Customer\Logout" name="vendor_module_observer_frontend_customer_logout_customer_logout"/>
       </event>
   </config>
   ```
2. Create Observer **Vendor/Module/Observer/Frontend/Customer/Logout.php**

   ```
    <?php
    /**
     * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    declare(strict_types=1);

    namespace Vendor\Module\Observer\Frontend\Customer;

    class Logout implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
    {

        /**
         * Execute observer
         *
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
         * @return void
         */
        public function execute(
            \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
        ) {
            //Your code here to clear the cookies
        }
    }
   ```

Comment: you save my day.